# Can "to bore" mean also to heckle/bait?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, synonyms

In Storm by Tim Minchin, Tim says in an argument about magic:

"Look uh, Storm, I don't mean to bore ya,
But there's no such thing as an aura."

Can bore here mean also to "scold" or to "come into her"?

Comment: IMO, it's a (less than ideal) word choice governed by the desire to have an off-rhyme with **aura**.  It means "to fail to hold a person's interest", not "scold".  I really doubt, in context, that it means "to drill a hole into".

Comment: No, it doesn't mean "scold" or anything like that.  I suspect the word "bore" was used partly to rhyme with "aura" (like TRomano says) and partly because Tim is implying, "**I am just going to keep saying the same thing**: there is no such thing as an aura."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is never the case. `to bore` is never going to mean to heckle/bait.

In this case the speaker is using the phrase `to bore` to mean disappoint or point out a flaw.